# E programming language - overview

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction

I need a basic overview of E programming language - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28programming_language%29

Could please someone that has used it, or knows its syntax give me a brief example of the following things:

Declaring and assigning values to variables: integer, floating point, string.

Conditional and loop statements,

Functions - syntax, writing and using functions, example,

Arrays - syntax, definition, example

I know that there is already info about this in their website, but they seem to have just written it without much examples or explanations.

Also could you please point me to a site, where I can download an E compiler, in order to play a little bit with the syntax and get some exercise in writing basic programs (the links in their website are all broken/moved etc.)

Thank you for your time.
Best regards!

Comment: Please do not confuse the E language with the *e* language. The latter is a functional hardware verification language, and the "e" tag applies to that language and not to E. I am removing that tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anton! The broad scope of your question unfortunately makes it inappropriate for this community. For future reference, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some guidelines on what is and what is not an appropriate SO question.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the link
[e programming](http://www.crockford.com/ec/manual.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply this website indeed has some really valuable information in it, but the link to the compiler is again dead. Do you happen to know where I can find and download it, as I will be needing it to create a simple app for a university project.